# Group by and sum/count of columns issues

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I am trying to to group_by program names and count the total column amounts per program. There are NA's in the mix.

Taking a data frame like this:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXX2B.png)

and getting something like in return [returned data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7oTX.png)

The following code only counts all non NA observations. It doesn't actually add up the numbers.  Do I  need to do some sort of ifelse here?  I also wonder if the !is.na causes it to count all non NA observations, however, if I remove it, I get all NA's as my totals.

```
df %>%  
  group_by(ProgramName) %>%
  summarise(ED = sum(!is.na(HighSchool)), EMP = sum(!is.na(Employment)))
```

alternatively, is there is a way to group by program name and count the observations ONLY if they had a 1 in either column, not to tally up the total? That is closer to what I want anyway.  Any support would be appreciated.

Comment: It's been a while since I did R, but try wrapping the value you want to negate in parentheses: `!(is.na(HighSchool))`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12109788) - good luck!

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful information regrading how to ask good questions, and how to use `dput()` instead of posting images of data. Thanks.

Comment: `aggregate(.~ProgramName, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = identity)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer both questions:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(ProgramName = c("Program A", "Program A", "Program A", 
"Program A", "Program B", "Program B", "Program B", "Program B", 
"Program C", "Program C", "Program C", "Program C"), HighSchool = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), Employment = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))


df %>%  
  group_by(ProgramName) %>%
  summarise(across(HighSchool:Employment, ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  ProgramName HighSchool Employment
  <chr>            <int>      <int>
1 Program A            2          1
2 Program B            2          3
3 Program C            3          2

# This is the one you state that you actually want
df %>%  
  group_by(ProgramName) %>%
  summarise(ED = sum(HighSchool == 1, na.rm = TRUE),
            EMP = sum(Employment == 1, na.rm = TRUE))

A tibble: 3 × 3
  ProgramName    ED   EMP
  <chr>       <int> <int>
1 Program A       2     1
2 Program B       2     3
3 Program C       3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum all non-NA values without needing to check for NA's or checking for values equalling 1:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~ProgramName, ~School, ~Employed,
         "Program A",       1,         0,
         "Program A",       0,         0,
         "Program A",       0,         1,
         "Program A",       1,         0,
         "Program B",       1,         1,
         "Program B",       0,         1,
         "Program B",       1,         1,
         "Program B",      NA,        NA,
         "Program C",       1,         0,
         "Program C",       1,         1,
         "Program C",      NA,        NA,
         "Program C",       1,         1
        )
df |> 
  summarise(
    ED = sum(School, na.rm = TRUE),
    EMP = sum(Employed, na.rm = TRUE),
    .by = ProgramName
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   ProgramName    ED   EMP
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Program A       2     1
#> 2 Program B       2     3
#> 3 Program C       3     2
```